# Cholesky factor of sparse matrices

Tags: matrices

If:

- $A$ is a symmetric, postive definite matrix,
- $L$ is the Cholesky factor of $A$ (a lower triangular Matrix) such that $A = LL^T$
- and $J_i (A) := \min\{ j : A_{ij}\neq 0\}$

then:

- $L_{ij} = 0$ for j$ < J_i (A)$

How could you prove this? Maybe by induction?

Comment: Yes, induction.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of applying [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to your post. Please use it in the future to make your question more readable.